# No wireless interfaces found RPi3 B

Tags: pi-3, wifi, raspbian-jessie

I had an issue with my old Rpi 3 model B that said no wireless interfaces found. I thought it was defective so I bought a new one. Plugged in the SD card (Jessie) and turned it on with the charger that came with it. 5v 2.5a charger. Still got the same issue. Ran ifconfig and wlan0 is still there and says

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:6f:b3:47
          inet6 addr: fe80::2f66:2a81:b61c:6c72/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

The onboard seems to be working and getting enough power...I am lost dont know how to fix

Comment: I added this auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0


iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid "ssid"
        wpa-psk "password" and i am able to connect via wfi now, but still on desktop says no wireless interfaces found

Answer (score 2):

I use these commands to 'reliably' connect the wireless interface

```
ifdown wlan0
nano /etc/network/interfaces
    allow-hotplug wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-ssid "router-loginid"
    wpa-psk "router-password"
    #wpa-config /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
systemctl restart networking
systemctl daemon-reload
ifup wlan0
dhcpcd wlan0
ifconfig wlan0
```

This fixes the issue of being unable to connect to the wireless network (OP had that issue in the beginning).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, hovering the mouse over network icon displayed the following message:
`Could not connect to dhcpcd5`
Once I ran it in terminal using
`sudo dhcpcd5`
...the icon started behaving normally.
I would suggest to add the above command in `/etc/rc.local` file so that you don't have to run it manually every time Pi boots up.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this issue.
Try this:

/etc/network/**interfaces** file

You may have made some changes  in it.(I had made some changes ,so I was getting

the "No wireless interfaces found"  issue )

You will need admin rights to edit that file so use **sudo nano**

The file by default should contain :

```
#commented text
#commented text
#commented text
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

If your file doesnt have this,then make the file as default and save it.
Reboot and you should be good to go.