# wlan0 not associated and No wireless interface found

Tags: networking, wifi, power-management

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with built-in wifi card. When I do run `ifconfig` I can find the wlan0 device. Before I never had a wifi problem until I connected the Raspberry Pi to my TV through the HDMI port. 
On my laptop, I can see that the access point is detected and working fine. The Raspberry Pi however is showing: **No wireless interfaces found**. 
[image]

When I hover the network icon, I can see the wlan0 saying that **wlan0 is not associated.** 
[image]

I tried disabling the Power management with the command `iwconfig wlan0 power off`  but nothing happens.
[image]

What happened to the wifi of my Raspberry pi?

**UPDATE 1**: Find below my wpa_supplicant.conf file

```
sudo leafpad /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file
```

[image]

Comment: try clicking the icon and entering the connection details

Comment: I tried, this is the result. https://photos.app.goo.gl/1kkecYPXeZV0P6LA3 not helpful

Comment: post your /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file (remove any sensitive info first)

Comment: Find my wpa_supplicant.conf file in the update 1 above

Comment: Does the red led flicker at all, or a small lightning bolt icon occasionally appear in a corner of the display?

Comment: The red led is on but not flickering. It's been 3 minutes that I observed it.

Comment: try commenting out (add a # to the beginning of the line) the unused network blocks in your wpa_supplicant.conf file, then reboot.

Comment: Nothing, I tried commenting the unused network then rebooted but nothing has changed. I also tried commenting all but no effect as well

Comment: Go through this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/75411/5538 ...and see if it helps narrow things down.

Comment: I managed to solve it

Comment: Can you say how you solved it? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: [https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/84247/86033](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/84247/86033) You should find your answer here.